# webrick and ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby, interpreter, rvm, ubuntu-10.04, webrick

Fist of all , I would say thank you to watch my post.

Secondly, the problem: if I type the ruby -v , how can I got witch ruby interpreter is talking to me ? I have two on my pc, one by rvm and one by a local directory.

So how can I figure out witch ruby is talking to me ?

How can I figure out what is the webrick using ?

I'm using ubuntu 10.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ which ruby
/home/lars/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
```

If you're using RVM, you can put `rvm 1.9.2` into the file `.rvmrc` in a project directory, and it will automatically be selected when you change to that directory. See [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/#project) for details.

Comment: Thank you ! It works fine!When i try to run the project on WebRick, it said missing mysql gem. But If i see the gem list, there is the mysql gem :( Somehow the webrick can't see the installed gem file. Can you tell me what should be the probmel ?

Comment: You need to post details about how you start Webrick, and the complete output with the error message. Also the output of gem list would help.